# I implemented custom authentication but how to get UserID through application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, authorize.net

I implemented custom authentication/authorization based on this tutorial http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx 
It works fine. I implemented it because I don't want to have stored procedures in my database and possibility to use different RDBMS.
But I have one issue here. I authenticate user but I don't know how to store UserId somewhere so when I need to get something from database based on UserID to get it. Something like:

```
List<Product> products = productsRepository.GetProductsByUserId(User.UserID);
```

How to make this?

BTW Is there any better way to make custom authentication/authorization than this from this tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you've actually implemented all the methods, and you're populating the built-in MembershipUser, then simply `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey` will return ther UserId.

Comment: Is there any example on the net how to implement that method? And I am now relay sure why in that tutorial User implement IPrincipal interface?

Comment: @1110 - IPrincipal has nothing to do with Membership.  FormsAuthentication takes care of IPrincipal.  Your custom membership provider sample should have an example of how to implement GetUser for your provider.

Answer (score 0):

in my solution I use

```
 Docent docent = DocentRepo.GetByID(User.Identity.Name);
```

maybe this can be of use to you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FormsAuthentification you can encode some custom user data in your cookie / ticket besides UserName. But you have to manually create a [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata.aspx) and set UserData property to the user's id during login. This way you can have both UserName & UserId.

```
        // during login
        var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        // preserve data in your configuration
        var ticketWithId = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                version: ticket.Version,
                                name: ticket.Name,
                                issueDate: ticket.IssueDate,
                                expiration: ticket.Expiration,
                                isPersistent: ticket.IsPersistent,
                                userData: userId);

        authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticketWithId);
        _context.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Then you can have an extension method for Controller or HttpContext classes:

```
    public int? GetUserId(this Controller controller) {
        var identity = (FormsIdentity)controller.User.Identity;
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(identity.Ticket.UserData, out id))
            return id;
        return null;
    }
```

But if you don't need both UserId & UserName data for your user, than `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` or `Controller.User.Identity.Name` will have the username for your current user